# Facebook Deeplink on Clicking via "App name"

Tags: ios, iphone, facebook, deep-linking

We can create a link using https://developers.facebook.com/quickstarts/526688910806462/?platform=app-links-host This will enable us to create an applink that will redirect you to our application or it will open appstore url in case the app is not installed on the device. It is working perfect. But now I want my app to be deeplinked when user clicks on appname in via "App Name" sharing post. This feature is already implemeted in Instagram. So, how can we do it from our appp. I just want to open my custome page by reaing url schema when we click on appName in Facebook.

Comment: I'm not sure which part of the UI do you mean by "via App Name"? If you're using custom Open Graph stories, for example "<doing custom action> on <app name>", I don't think it's supported. Any sample code or screenshot?

Comment: Please try to share on facebook via Instagram, in that when we click on insagram it opens that photo in Instagram app. I am looking for that functionality.

Comment: I can't find other apps that have the same behaviour. I suspect it's Instagram-specific (i.e. non-public).